# "That's the idea that someone does" vs. "it has the idea of someone does"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, nouns

I'm trying to explain what something means. Is it correct to express that using the word "idea" as follows?

> 1. He pulls up next to him. To pull up (pause). That's the idea that someone does X.
> 2. He pulls up next to him. To pull up (pause). It has the idea of someone does X.

Comment: It would be helpful to give us more context here. The *it* in the second sentence appears to be a pronoun referring back to a noun, whereas the *it* in the first sentence appears to be dummy subject as in *It's good to see you.*.

Comment: Look at my update.

Comment: "It gives the idea of someone doing X." Also, may be "it gives the idea that someone does X." The former is what you need. I wouldn't use the latter, instead I would say "it suggests that someone does X."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression neither *is* nor *has* an idea: it *expresses* or *conveys* an idea. But more simply, it *means*.

So

> That conveys the idea that somebody does X

or more usually

> That means that somebody does X

Also, *the idea of* requires a noun phrase, not a verbal phrase, so

> That conveys the idea of somebody('s) doing X

would be OK. (I put the *'s* in parentheses because some grammarians insist on it, but many people don't use it even in writing: see [this explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_verbs#Note_on_possessives_and_personal_pronouns_used_with_the_-ing_form))

Answer (score 2):

Your statement (quoted) doesn't provide a clear picture of your suggestion to someone. You may find the usage in any dictionary. For instance, on M-W:

***Usage**: It is usually considered correct to say that someone has the idea of doing  something, rather than the idea to do  it: he had the idea of taking  (not the idea to take ) a short holiday*

Answer (score 1):

In your two examples, "It's the idea that ..." and "It has the idea of ..." do not convey any sensible or clear idea to me.  Perhaps the phrase you want instead is "The idea is ...".

For example, after presenting an instance or two that in some way illustrate X, one says "The idea is that X occurred", to make explicit what the examples were intended to show.